# "Permission Denied" error in IE after adding content editor to form

Tags: javascript, permissions, error, internet-explorer

A site that I have not modified in several weeks has suddenly stopped functioning in Internet Explorer as it has for the past few months. I have a content editor in my list on the New, Display, and Edit forms for a list. Firefox, Chrome, and Opera all load up these pages along with the data in the content editors just fine while Internet Explorer will not load my file and will actually give me a "Permission Denied" error (if I have developer tools open).

I have not changed anything in the files themselves which should've caused this issue, and I actually confirmed that it was not bad code or file reference by clearing out the .txt file it was referencing. Access to the txt file itself is not an issue, as it does successfully hide everything I specified in that file through CSS. It's just the JavaScript which doesn't work. After I removed the content editor web part, I stopped receiving the "Permission Denied" error which was appearing when I had developer tools opened. I added another empty content editor back onto the page, and the same error appeared.

note:
There was a network update which happened within my network and may have changed some settings, but the only discussion I found about settings that might cause this were referring to adding the site to the Trusted Sites list (it was) and disabling debugging (it was). None of the users within my local office are able to load the forms normally as we were a few days ago, but my main concern is about the users of this site who are located in another country and have not yet received these system updates. When the site stops working for them, it's my head.. as "Use FireFox" is not an acceptable response after they just decommissioned their old Lotus Notes in acceptance of our SP site. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any suspicious events in uls logs? Can you use html form web part on these pages?

Answer (score 0):

Please  do the following steps :-

a) Go to Central Administration
b) Select your web application
c) Click on **Web Part Security** under **Security** tab
d) Select the option **Allows contributors to add or edit scriptable Web Parts**.
e) Also validate the other settings.

Regards,
Anurag

Comment: Actually, would this even apply if I am in a user group with Full Control on the site and I am also an SCA?